# Populating RadAutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-phone

How do I populate a `RadAutoСompleteBox`.

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <Dropdownitems> 
             <item text = 1>
             <item text = 2>
        </DropDownitems>
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

The dropdownitems make no sense, I was just trying to portray what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xaml:**

```
    <telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="AutoCompleteBox"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

**Cs:**

```
    var suggestions = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        suggestions.Add("suggestion" + i);

    AutoCompleteBox.SuggestionsSource = suggestions;
```

Helpful information about [RadAutoCompleteBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radautocompletebox-overview.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a Way to Only do it on the Xaml side?

Comment: I don't think so. Check the link in my answer :)